# No se ejecuta la animación si llamo al método que la ejecuta desde el mismo JFrame

Tags: java, animación

Tengo mi clase Frame con dos botones, y lo que quiero es que al presionar el **btnMover**, el **btnBoton** se mueva y se vea la animación de como lo hace. Si al botón **btnMover** le añado una acción que llame al método que mueve al otro botón, se mueve pero no se ve la animación, sin embargo si creo otra clase en la cual creo una instancia de mi Frame y en esta clase es que llamo al método sí que se ve la animación, cómo puedo hacer para que se vea la animación al hacer click sobre el botón sin necesidad de crear otra clase. Gracias

Mi clase Frame que al hacer click no se ve la animación:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton btnBoton;
    private JButton btnMover;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Frame r = new Frame();
        r.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public Frame() {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 751, 474);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        btnBoton = new JButton("Boton");
        btnBoton.setBounds(233, 318, 115, 45);
        contentPane.add(btnBoton);
        
        btnMover = new JButton("Mover");
        btnMover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mover();
            }
        });
        btnMover.setBounds(58, 62, 115, 45);
        contentPane.add(btnMover);
    }

    public void mover() {
        int x = btnBoton.getX();
        int y = btnBoton.getY();
        for(int k=0; k<100; k++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            btnBoton.setLocation(++x, y);
        }
        
    }
}
```

La clase donde creo una instancia y llamo al método de mover() pero no es esto lo que quiero

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.mover();
    }

}
```

Comment: pues tendrias que poner r.mover() en el main de la clase frame para que se ejecute el metodo al ejecutar la clase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada debes tener siempre en cuenta que *Swing* funciona en base a un unico hilo de ejecucion, eso quiere decir que con cualquier llamada de largo procesamiento/espera/bloqueo desde cualquier contexto de eventos (en este caso `ActionListener`) no dejara que la interfaz grafica refleje la 'animacion' en tiempo real sino que se queda a la espera o casi congelada hasta que el Event Dispatch Thread termine y la *GUI* solo mostrara a secas la nueva posicion del componente.

Basicamente el truco es utilizar un *thread* independiente para realizar ésta tarea. Una manera entre varias que existen es por ejemplo implementar un [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html) y un [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html).

En *Frame.java*...

```
btnMover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //mover();
    TimerTask animTask=new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        mover();
      }
    };
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(animTask,0,2*60*1000);
  }
});
```

Puedes ver algo mas acerca de la [concurrencia en Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) y/o alternativamente como usar [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ha sido de mucha ayuda